# How to add a camera on a robot in the stage simulator?

Tags: ros, simulator-stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the web page of stage_ros wiki, I notice several topics including:
odom (nav_msgs/Odometry)
base_scan (sensor_msgs/LaserScan)
base_pose_ground_truth (nav_msgs/Odometry)
image (sensor_msgs/Image)
depth (sensor_msgs/Image)
camera_info (sensor_msgs/CameraInfo)

However, when I launch turtlebot_stage. I don't find any depth or camera_info. I want to know that how to add a camera on a robot in the stage simulator. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224000/how-to-add-a-camera-on-a-robot-in-the-stage-simulator?/) by [Minglong](https://answers.ros.org/users/23257/minglong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-01-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the link to stage documentation http://rtv.github.io/Stage/group__model__camera.html . Usage is pretty simple, just add the snippet to your robot and it should output data on "/depth".

---

Originally posted by [semael23](https://answers.ros.org/users/4206/semael23/) with karma: 31 on 2016-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0